# How to fix libpng in android

Tags: java, android, apk, libpng

I have submitted my release apk to the Google Play console, however it was rejected due to a libpng security vulnerability. I have a couple of libraries I use in my app. How do I know which of these uses libpng ?
i try to fix it by changed files but keep same problem when i publish it in google play he told me that my apk has a libpng pleas how i can fix it

http://freecode-source.blogspot.com/2017/01/super-max-super-mario-free-code-source.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check Which one of your libraries uses Libpng manipulates your png images in your app? you can find mainly in their documentations
Libpng versions should be v1.0.66, v.1.2.56, v.1.4.19, v1.5.26 or Higher
https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7011127?hl=en

Comment: that is the problem haha i don't find this libraries